# RecyclerView in CardView another RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I Am newbie in Android. I need to contains `RecyclerView` in  `CardView` another `RecyclerView`, like on this image:

[image: this]

I try to do this, but second `RecyclerView` not displayed, and if i add more than one items in first `RecyclerView`, i have error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LayoutManager android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@413cfb40 is already attached to a RecyclerView: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{413d2c38 VFED.... ......ID 0,45-438,45 #7f0c0083 app:id/noteRecyclerView}
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(RecyclerView.java:1007)
    at com.monz.project_note.app.Adapter.NoteListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NoteListAdapter.java:56)
    at com.monz.project_note.app.Adapter.NoteListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NoteListAdapter.java:26)
```

### Here is my code:

**Label adapter:**

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.monz.project_note.app.R;
import java.util.List;

public class LabelListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LabelListAdapter.LabelViewHolder> {
    private List<String> data;
    private LabelViewHolder holder;

    public LabelListAdapter(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    public LabelViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.label_item, parent, false);
        return new LabelViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LabelViewHolder holder, int position) {
        this.holder = holder;
        String str = data.get(position);
        this.holder.label.setText(str);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public static class LabelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        private TextView label;

        public LabelViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.label_card_item);
        }
    }

    public void removeAt(int position) {
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, data.size());
    }
}
```

**Note Adapter:**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.monz.project_note.app.Note;
import com.monz.project_note.app.R;
import java.util.List;

public class NoteListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteListAdapter.NoteViewHolder> {
    private List<Note> data;
    private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
    private LabelListAdapter lla;
    private   LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerItem;

    public NoteListAdapter(List<Note> data, LinearLayoutManager mn)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.layoutManagerItem = mn;
    }

    @Override
    public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_item, parent, false);
        return new NoteViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NoteViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Note item = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.author.setText(item.getAuthor());
        holder.date.setText(item.getDate());
        holder.setId(item.getId());
        lla = new LabelListAdapter(item.getLabels());
        holder.rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerItem);
        holder.rv.setAdapter(lla);
        if (item.isCommon_access()) {
            holder.access.setText("Public");
        } else {
            holder.access.setText("Private");
        }
        holder.getCardView().setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(item.getColor()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public interface MyClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v, NoteViewHolder nvl);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }

    public static class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private CardView cardView;
        private int id;
        private TextView title;
        private TextView author;
        private TextView date;
        private TextView access;
        private RecyclerView rv;

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getUniq() {
            return id;
        }

        public TextView getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public CardView getCardView() {
            return cardView;
        }

        public NoteViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.noteCardView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
            author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_author);
            date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_date);
            access = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_access);
            rv = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.noteRecyclerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v, this);
        }
    }

    public void removeAt(int position) {
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, data.size());
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.monz.project_note.app.Adapter.NoteListAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private RecyclerView rv;

    private List<Note> list;
    private NoteListAdapter nla;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppDefault);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initToolbar();
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainRecyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                TextView userTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernameTitle);
                if (userTitle != null)
                    userTitle.setText("Hello " + getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            }
        });
    }


    private void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.titleText);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        System.exit(0);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data == null)
            return;
        boolean delete = data.getBooleanExtra("delete", false);
        if (delete)
            return;
        String title = data.getStringExtra("title");
        String text = data.getStringExtra("text");
        String date = data.getStringExtra("date");
        ArrayList<String> labels = data.getStringArrayListExtra("labels");
        boolean access = data.getBooleanExtra("access", true);
        String color = data.getStringExtra("color");
        LinearLayoutManager mn = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        nla = new NoteListAdapter(list, mn);

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("change", false)) {
            for (Note n : list) {
                if (n.getId() == getIntent().getIntExtra("id", -1)) {
                    list.remove(n);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        list.add(0, new Note(title, text, access, color, getIntent().getStringExtra("name"), date, labels));
        rv.setAdapter(nla);



        nla.setOnItemClickListener(new NoteListAdapter.MyClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View v, NoteListAdapter.NoteViewHolder nvl) {
                for (Note n : list) {
                    if (n.getId() == nvl.getUniq()) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateNoteActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("new", false);
                        intent.putExtra("access", n.isCommon_access());
                        intent.putExtra("title", n.getTitle());
                        intent.putExtra("text", n.getText());
                        intent.putExtra("color", n.getColor());
                        intent.putExtra("id", n.getId());
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                nla.removeAt(position);
            }
        });

    }

    public void onFABClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateNoteActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
        intent.putExtra("new", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    }
}
```

### XML files:

**XML 1 :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/mainBackground"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mainRecyclerView"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_plus"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:onClick="onFABClick" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"/>

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**XML 2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/note_item_layout"
    android:background="@color/mainBackground">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/noteCardView"
        card:cardElevation="2dp"
        card:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card:contentPadding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/noteRecyclerView"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_author"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_access"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have to give a static height to `CardView`, otherwise you can use this [library](https://github.com/hrskrs/android-linear-layout-manager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/solovyev/android/views/llm/LinearLayoutManager.java)

Comment: TY! Static height help me!